# JSF Richfaces PopupPanel refresh form not working

Tags: jsf-2

I have a problem with the data on a rich:popupPanel not being refreshed in the following case:

1. When the user first opens the  popup panel  the values are brought from the bean and are displaye.
2. The user changes some values  then decides not to save the changes and hits the close button.
3. Then he opens the popup again. When the dialog is opened again, in the backing bean , the values for the relevances are correctly changed back to the previous values(load() is called) but this update is not reflected in the UI.
   The user can see the values that he has chosen just before (step 2.), not the ones that are on the backing bean.

Do you happen to know any solution for forcing an update for the components of the popup panel with values from the backing bean once it is opened in the browser?
I don't have this problem if the data is displayed on a separate page, not on a popupPanel, but i need to use popup Panel from the requirements.

Here is the code:
1. Component that opens the popuppanel

```
<a4j:commandLink id="config" value="open" action="#{bean.load()}"
oncomplete="#{rich:component('configPopUp:pp')}.show();" execute="@this">                           
</a4j:commandLink>
```

2. popuppanel

   ```
    <rich:popupPanel id="ConfigPopUp"  width="800" height="350" title=" "> 
    <h:form id="ConfigForm">
           <div class="row " style="margin: 0px">
             <div >
               <a4j:commandButton styleClass="pull-right" id="ConfigSave"
                   actionListener="#{bean.saveConfiguration()}"
                   value="#{text['Configuration.save']}" immediate="true">
               </a4j:commandButton>
           </div>
       </div>                      

        <ui:repeat
           value="#{bean.selectedValues}"  var="current" varStatus="i">
           <div class="row" style="margin: 0px">
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 ">
                   <h:outputText value="#{current.text}" />
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                   <rich:select value="#{current.relevance}">
                       <f:selectItems
                           value="#{bean.relevanceOptions}"/>
                       <f:ajax event="change" render="@form" execute="@this" />
                   </rich:select>
               </div>                  
           </div>
       </ui:repeat>

     </h:form>
     </rich:popupPanel>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal panels doesnt automatically re-render on .hide(), so its "normal" that the backing bean has the correct info but the panel not

You can fix it by adding the "render" attribute to the commandLink with the panel's id (or the panel's cointener element).

```
<a4j:commandLink id="config" value="open" action="#{bean.load()}"
   oncomplete="#{rich:component('configPopUp:pp')}.show();" render ="ConfigPopUp" execute="@this">                           
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Another solution is to use domElementAttachment = "parent" into the popupPanel, you can read of it on [rich_modalPanel documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html)

Hope it helps